# Could not find implicit value for parameter Mapper

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, shapeless

I try to create a simple shapeless based function to convert the case class into a list of string I could then encode as csv.

The point of this is to summon type class `CsvEncoder` on every member of the case class and then invoke method `encode` to change it to string.

Type class:

```
trait CsvEncoder[T] {
  def encode(t: T): String
}

trait LowPriorityEncoder {
  implicit def genericEncoder[T]: CsvEncoder[T] = _.toString
}

object CsvEncoder extends LowPriorityEncoder {

  implicit def optionEncoder[T](
      implicit e: CsvEncoder[T]
  ): CsvEncoder[Option[T]] = _.fold("")(e.encode)

}
```

And shapeless:

```
class CsvBuilder[Row](rows: List[Row]) {

  object csvMapper extends Poly1 {

    implicit def caseEncode[V](
        implicit e: CsvEncoder[V]
    ): Case.Aux[FieldType[Symbol, V], FieldType[Symbol, String]] =
      at[FieldType[Symbol, V]](s => field[Symbol](e.encode(s)))
  }

  def build[Repr <: HList, OutRepr <: HList](
      implicit labelledGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[Row, Repr],
      mapper: Mapper.Aux[csvMapper.type, Repr, OutRepr],
      toMap: ToMap.Aux[OutRepr, Symbol, String]
  ): List[Map[String, String]] = {

    def transform(row: Row): Map[String, String] = {
      val formattedRows = labelledGeneric
        .to(row)
        .map(csvMapper)

      val fields = toMap(formattedRows)
        .map {
          case (k: Symbol, value: String) =>
            (k.toString -> value)
        }

      fields
    }

    rows.map(transform(_))

  }
}
```

When I try to use with simple case class:

```
final case class ProjectCsvRow(
    project: Option[String],
    something: Option[String],
    site: Option[String],
    state: Option[Int]
)

new CsvBuilder[ProjectCsvRow](
  List(ProjectCsvRow(Some(""), None, None, None))
).build
```

I'm getting

> could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper.Aux[stabilizer$1.csvMapper.type,Repr,OutRepr]

I think I'm missing something, but I can't really figure it out.

I already checked if there's instance of `CsvEncoder` for every field.

Comment: The time I did something very similar to this I found it was way easier to just forget about all the fancy stuff like `Poly` and just write a classic head-tail decoder. I may add an answer with that approach if you find it helpful? Or maybe you already tried that and didn't work for some reason?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your `Poly` is incorrect. Type `Symbol` is too rough. Keys of a record are not just `Symbol`s, they are singleton subtypes of `Symbol`. You should define

```
object csvMapper extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseEncode[K <: Symbol, V](
    implicit e: CsvEncoder[V]
  ): Case.Aux[FieldType[K, V], FieldType[K, String]] =
    at[FieldType[K, V]](s => field[K](e.encode(s)))
}
```

Secondly, making a `Poly` nested into a class (rather than object) can be dangerous (it starts to depend on an instance of `CsvBuilder` and therefore on type `Row`). So move `csvMapper` outside `CsvBuilder` (so that its path is stable).

Comment: Thanks, I refactored my solution to use typeclass derivation, but it's good to know what I did wrong.